# Color a vector field depending on the value of the component z of the vectors

Tags: graphics3d, color, vector

I need to color this vector field. I want the vectors that have negative z component to be colored different that those ones with positive z component. 
This is the vector field:

```
table = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/rjM2i5Jt", "Table", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True];

X = table[[;; , ;; 3]];
V = table[[;; , 4 ;; 6]];

g = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads@.015, Arrow@Transpose[{X, X + .07 Normalize /@ V}]}, 
           BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
           ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, Boxed -> False
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads@.015, {If[Subtract@@#[[;;,3]] <= 0, Red, Blue], 
     Arrow[#]}& /@ Transpose[{X, X + .07 Normalize /@ V}]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, now i would like to do the same in a 2d vector field. I graphic the cutting planes with these lines.

Comment: table = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/rjM2i5Jt", 
   "Table", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True];
X = table[[;; , ;; 2]];
V = table[[;; , 4 ;; 5]];
Graphics [{Arrowheads@.015, 
  Arrow@Transpose[{X, X + .02 Normalize /@ V}]}]

I would like to the same as before. Color the vectors to differentiate the ones that have postive z component  from the others.
Take account that here the x component is not in the graphic

Comment: z component*...

Comment: @Franco, does this give what you need: `Graphics[{Arrowheads@.015, {If[Subtract @@ #[[;; , 2]] <= 0, Red, 
      Blue], Arrow[#]} & /@ Transpose[{X, X + .07 Normalize /@ V}]}]`?

Comment: Thank you again, you are solving all my problems! I will make the last question. Could i color the arrow with a gradient? In other words, color the arrows that have greater z component darker than the rest and keeping the two colors (negative and positives values).

Comment: I have noticed that you misunderstood what i tried to explain the last commentary. I have the 2D vector field in which I graphic xy cutting planes with  the component x,y of the vector field. I would like to differentiate the vector with negative z component from the ones with positive z componet despite this component is not involved in the graphic.